# When you've done an ambulatory surgery

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure, sentence-choice, register

I was wondering if someone could let me know which one of the following self-made sentences sounds more natural in the way that it could be more understood not only by well-educated people of English language:

> a) I had an outpatient surgery 1 hour ago.
>
> b) I had a same day surgery 1 hour ago.
>
> c) I had an ambulatory surgery 1 hour ago.

Meanwhile, I'm not sure if they are natural structurally. If so, then please let me know how a native would call fast and easy type of surgeries?

P.S. I think they are very scientific terms which are rarely used in everyday conversations to indicate what I'm going to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In AmE, we wouldn't use the article with **surgery**:

> He had *outpatient surgery* earlier today.
>
> He underwent  *outpatient surgery* earlier today.

But we would use it with **operation**:

> He had *an outpatient operation* earlier today.

In AmE, **surgery** in this locution is understood to be a  process, whereas the **operation** is that which is accomplished during the surgical process.

Of the two, **operation** is the more colloquial. Since you ask about those who are not well-educated: there are some speakers of American English who have had little experience of hospitals for a variety of social, economic, and political reasons, and speakers who are marginally literate, and a person who falls into both groups might not use the word **outpatient** and certainly not the word **ambulatory**. They might express the idea with a circumlocution:

> He had an operation this morning, the kind where you are in and out in an hour.
>
> He had an operation this morning, the kind where you can go home right afterwards.
>
> He had an operation this morning, the kind where you can go home the same day.
>
> He had an operation this morning, but not the kind where you have to stay in the hospital overnight.

Answer (score -3):

The verb *perform* is what typically goes with the noun *surgery*:

> I **performed** a surgery an hour ago.

Comment: But not if you're the patient.